# the toggle switch is getting disabled after refreshing the page

Tags: angular2-template

```
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="toggle-switch toggle-switch--blue">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-switch__checkbox" (change)="checkisPetBondAvailable($event)" >
                          <i class="toggle-switch__helper"></i>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is the code for toggle switch where its getting disabled after refreshing the page can i get any solution for it

Comment: can you please create a plunker for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer in above code we should use [checked] for two way binding